# jQuery fade all other images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I made this code with jQuery to fade images (**but not the one** a move the mouse over) and **all images fade** at the same time!

```
$(".playThumb").fadeTo("normal", 1);

$(".playThumb").hover(function() {
    $(".playThumb").each(function() {
        if ( $(this) != $(this) ) {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
        }
    });
}, function() {
    $(".playThumb").each(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    });
});

<a href="#"><img src="001.jpg" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="002.jpg" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="003.jpg" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="004.jpg" class="playThumb" />
```

If someone can help me to fade all other images **except the one I point the mouse over** ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use [`not`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/not) to filter out the element being hovered:

```
$(".playThumb").fadeTo("normal", 1);

$(".playThumb").hover(function() {
    $(".playThumb").not(this).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
}, function() {
    $(".playThumb").not(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
});
```

Comment: pretty sure you don't need $() around "this" in the not.

Comment: Ok, I've removed the $() now.